# BackboneJS and Codeigniter - Display multiple RESTful APIs in the same View

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter, backbone.js

Ok, I try to explain it as best as possible. I have a MySQL database with a table called `artists` which stores artists/bands from a-z. I'm using the PHP framework Codeigniter for my backend. Now I have made a JSON file which I, through a Model and Collection, render in a specific view. My JSON looks like this:

```
[
{
    "name":"0-9",
    "id":"0",
    "url":"0-9"
},
{
    "name":"A",
    "id":"1",
    "url":"A"
},
{
    "name":"B",
    "id":"2",
    "url":"B"
},
{
    "name":"C",
    "id":"3",
    "url":"C"
},
{
    "name":"D",
    "id":"4",
    "url":"D"
},
    ....etc etc.
```

Then my HTML template looks like this (using Handlebars):

```
<ol class="alist">
    {{#each alphabetlist}}
    <li data-id="{{this.url}}">{{this.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ol>
```

And my View looks like this:

```
function(Backbone,Handlebars, Template) {


    'use strict';

    var AlphabetListView = Backbone.View.extend({

        template: Handlebars.compile(Template),

        events: {
            'click li':'li_clickHandler'
        },

        li_clickHandler: function(e) {
            var id = $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-id');
            Backbone.history.navigate('/artists/'+id, {trigger:true});
        },

        render: function() {
            $(this.el).html(this.template({alphabetlist:this.collection.toJSON()}));
            return this;
        }

    });

    return AlphabetListView;

}
```

So, what I want to do is, to create an API for each letter, using the RESTful API plugin from Codeigniter. I create an API for each letter. For example like this for the letter **C**:

```
  <?php

  require(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

 class Cartists extends REST_Controller{

 public function index_get()  
 { 
  $this->load->database();
  $sql = 'SELECT id, name FROM artists WHERE name LIKE="C%"';
  $query = $this->db->query($sql);
  $data = $query->result();

  if($data) {
      $this->response($data, 200); // 200 being the HTTP response code
    } else {
     $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t find any artists with letter c!'), 404);
 }
}
```

Then, in my Backbone Model I do:

```
function($, Backbone) {
var CartistsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "../ci/index.php/api/cartists/index",

    defaults: {
        "id": '',
        "name": ''
    }
});

return CartistsModel ;
});
```

And my Collection:

```
function(Backbone, CartistsModel ) {
var CartistsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: CartistsModel ,
    url: "../ci/index.php/api/cartists/index"
});

return CartistsCollection;
 });
```

Now my goal is that I get the right collection after clicking the relevant letter. For example clicking the letter C, it shows me all artists with the letter C. When I click letter M, it shows me all artists with M etc etc. I feel i'm close, but right now I'm kind of lost or dont really know how to solve this...

Any suggestions?

Comment: so, what is the problem?

Comment: @GonzaloNaveira So when I create a model/collection for each letter, should I fetch all these collections in my main router in the `initilaize`-function and how or when do i render them?

Comment: You named your class Cartists, because it represents all the "C" artists? You should make the class Artists and a method "letter($letter)"Then you could access like "/artists/letter/c" there you fetch all the data for the letter, not in the main!